# How can I search all fields include query text partially?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using `$text` and `$search` to search fields including query text partially.

For example, fields is following.

```
{ first_name: "Frist Name", last_name: "Last Name", email:"name@email.com"}
```

If I type "na" in search field, I want to get all fields including "na".

How can I get fields on `node.js`.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you want to use a regex, be aware though that this does NOT use the text index you've built.

it would look like this:

```
  {email: new RegExp(".*na.*")}
```